# How to redirect url contains .aspx to ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to upgrade web form project (`.aspx`) to ASP.NET Core Web API. Web form project only returns xml based on query string passing in url (e.g. `default.aspx?q=test&category=test_category`).

For this, I will rewrite the complete new project in .NET 6. But I want to preserve the url (e.g. `default.aspx?q=test&category=test_category`) because this is used in many places e.g. Android and iOS app.

How I can write a middleware that redirects to specific controller action and returns the xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think [MapControllerRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapdefaultcontrollerroute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) will handle what you need. In your program.cs or startup.cs:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "DefaultRedirect",
    pattern: "Default.aspx",
    defaults: new { controller = "NewController", action = "NewAction" });
```

All of the querystring values will be preserved and sent to your new controller and function, in this case "NewController" and "NewAction" respectively.